# How can I read Beyond2020 data into R?

Tags: r

The French statistical national institute provides detailled data in the Beyond2020 data format (see [an example](http://telechargement.insee.fr/fichiersdetail/SIDENOMB2013/beyond/SIDENOMB2013_denent2013_beyond.zip)). I don't know how to read or import those dataset into R ? Does anyone has a solution ?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the data-browser software from http://www.insee.fr/en/publications-et-services/default.asp?page=services/beyond/beyond.htm , and exporting from there? I haven't tried it, but it might help.

Comment: The Data-Browser software isn't available for Mac.